# While statement not displaying ECHO

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

the code below is display the else statement, but when $getlogin == 0 it is not displaying

```
while ($getlogin = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin)) {
        if ($getlogin == 0) {
            echo "NOTHING TO DISPLAY";
        }
        else{
            echo $getlogin['username'];
            echo $getlogin['password'];
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is correct ! show other code snippet and use mysqli_* function

Comment: A resultset row is not `0`.  Please stop using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: Please [don't use `mysql_*`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1); the `mysql_*` functions are outdated, [deprecated](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and insecure - they have been removed entirely from modern versions of PHP (version 7.0 and higher). Use [`MySQLi`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: This code snippet has nothing wrong except you are using `mysql_` interface, which is almost dead. We cannot pinpoint the problem just by looking at this very little detailed snippet..

Comment: thank you guys, i will update my self in mysqli or PDO, but for now, it is not displaying the echo"NOTHING TO DISPLAY".

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: @RomeoSierra That code snippet is so full of alarm bells it should be deafening.

Comment: @tadman Didn't get you...

Comment: @RomeoSierra `$checklogin` undoubtedly contains untold security problems as this is a home-rolled login system.

Comment: @tadman You are being judgmental.. :D

Comment: @RomeoSierra I've seen way too many questions here with apocalyptically bad security holes. Remember, it only takes *one* tiny slip and your site can be cracked wide open.

Comment: @tadman Yup.. I totally agree with you.. :) When I said *there's nothing wrong* I was referring to syntactical aspects. Semantically, there is a multitude of problems here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   $checklogin = mysql_query($queryContents);

    if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin)== 0){
       echo "NOTHING TO DISPLAY";
    }
    else{
       while($getlogin = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin)) {

         var_dump($getlogin);

       }
    }
```

you can use php empty function also to check empty
like this

```
if (empty($checklogin)) {
       echo 'NOTHING TO DISPLAY';
}else{
    while($getlogin = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin)) {
       var_dump($getlogin);
     }
}
```